# Uploading an Article to Joomla 3.6 using a PHP Script

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.6

For the past years we have used a local application that uploads articles to our Joomla homepage (Using a PHP Script). After the latest update to Joomla 3.6 (Used to be 3.5) that application no longer works. The following error occurs:

```
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/var/www/DOMAIN/htdocs/FOLDER/execute.php" at line 1.
```

There used to be an "application.php" file inside ./htdocs/FOLDER/administrator/includes/ and after the update the file disappeared. It looks like the script can't create an instance of the application. I have already tried to repair the Database using the Back End option, but that didn't solve the problem.

Update: The above error occurs at:

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('administrator');
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you please paste the code which you are using to update an article?

Comment: I currently have no access to the code, waiting for my colleague to send it to me. (He maintains the application and does the scripting).

Comment: Is there a known problem with the 3.6 update that could refer to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Some text is being output by "/var/www/DOMAIN/htdocs/FOLDER/execute.php", probably white space at line one. Check nothing is output before sending any headers.

Not a great resolution but you could also clean the output buffer before the header fn. Have a read of [ob_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php)

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the white space and ob_clean(), I will try it out as soon as I can and update you guys

Comment: no worries Phil. As mentioned ob_clean isn't really a solution to the issue. I would call exit before the error and inspect the response to check for data/output. Keep moving the exit up the code until you find where the output disappears